# Does RStudio's build button not work properly?

Tags: r, windows

If I build from RStudio => Install and Restart, I get

[image]

However, if I install `stringi` and restart, the error remains the same.
If I run from console:

```
roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
Loading imsbasics
Error: Dependency package(s) 'devtools','fBasics','lubridate' not available.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: roxygen2 requires Encoding: UTF-8 
2: In (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
  Dependency package 'devtools' not available.
3: In (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
  Dependency package 'fBasics' not available.
4: In (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error: Dependency package(s) 'devtools','fBasics','lubridate' not available.
 Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anybody understand why RStudio gives the wrong error message?
(Console output is different!)

**Edit:** After installing everything, `devtools::build()` works, but `Ctrl + Shift + B` still does NOT work => same error in RStudio!

Comment: Try installing `install.packages(c("devtools", "fBasics", "lubridate", "stringi"))`. Also note that this is a R thing, Rstudio is "just" an IDE.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Still the same error - see my edit above. When I ran `install.packages("stringi")`, it threw an error for the first time, after restart RStudio + install again everything is ok now. If you have a clue, what could have happend, just write an answer. Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that when you build through Rstudio it loads a new R session that doesn't have access to the folder with installed packages (`.libPaths()`).